# tweenjs raster images flickering scaling animation on iPads

Tags: javascript, ios, canvas, createjs, tween.js

I have a weird problem when animating images with tweenjs on iOS. For raster images, such as png it flickers a lot.
It's most noticeable on iPads. Probably because of the larger screen. SVG images animate just fine at the same time, so it's not a performance issue.
Is there a way to improve the animation for raster images?
Here's a link to my test [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cL1b0rm0/)

```
function init() {
  var stage = new createjs.Stage("demoCanvas");
  var circle = new createjs.Bitmap('https://rawgit.com/damy90/createjs-bugs/master/ipad-scale-lag/finish.svg');
  circle.x = 100;
  circle.y = 100;
  circle.regX= 84;
  circle.regY= 26.5;
  circle.width = 168;
  circle.head = 53;

  var circle2 = new createjs.Bitmap('https://rawgit.com/damy90/createjs-bugs/master/ipad-scale-lag/finish.png');
  circle2.x = 100;
  circle2.y = 200;
  circle2.regX= 84;
  circle2.regY= 26.5;

  var circle3 = new createjs.Bitmap('https://rawgit.com/damy90/createjs-bugs/master/ipad-scale-lag/finish-big.png');
  circle3.x = 300;
  circle3.y = 200;
  circle3.regX = 160;
  circle3.regY = 53;
  circle3.scaleX = 0.5;
  circle3.scaleY = 0.5;

  stage.addChild(circle, circle2, circle3);

  createjs.Tween.get(circle, { loop: true })
    .to({scaleX: 1.1, scaleY: 1.1}, 1000)
    .to({scaleX: 1, scaleY: 1}, 1000);

  createjs.Tween.get(circle2, { loop: true })
    .to({scaleX: 1.1, scaleY: 1.1}, 1000)
    .to({scaleX: 1, scaleY: 1}, 1000);

  createjs.Tween.get(circle3, { loop: true })
    .to({scaleX: 0.55, scaleY: 0.55}, 1000)
    .to({scaleX: 0.5, scaleY: 0.5}, 1000);

  createjs.Ticker.setFPS(30);
  createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", stage);
  setTimeout(function(){
    circle2.cache(-2, -2, 172, 57);
    circle3.cache(-2, -2, 340, 110);
 }, 500);
}

init();
```

The 1-st one is svg, the second one - png and the 3-th - scaled down png.

Comment: Using the debugger and tracing into the function `createjs.Ticker.setFPS` i see that `Ticker` will run in several different modes. When I output to the console `console.log(createjs.Ticker.useRAF)` after the call `setFPS` it outputs `false` which would explain the flickering (should be true i think). You should see the createjs documentation on how to force synced animation using RAF

Comment: createjs.Ticker.timingMode = createjs.Ticker.RAF_SYNCHED;
Is this how I'm supposed to do it? It didn't work. Anyway, I don't think the framerate is the problem. I have 2 PNG and 1 SVG animations running simultaneously in the example and only the PNG ones are flickering.
Also, I found out that the SVG flickers on Firefox unless I cache it, which then causes flickering in iPads.

Comment: The problem is I dont know what you mean by flickering, To me it means that at some frames of the animation parts of the image have not been rendered causing a flicker. Some people take it to mean that the animation is not smooth making it seam to flicker (jitter) as it moves.

Comment: Oh and RAF_SYNCHED would be the option to use.

Comment: There is trebling in high contrast areas, small borders are shrinking or disappearing and reappearing. For instance the shadow on the text in the example can disappear and reappear rapidly and the border on the button can change its width noticeably.

Comment: Your problem is not due to any failing of software or hardware but the inherent in process of scaling content on a bitmaped screen.Look for image Smoothing, and  image Quality settings (image quality has limited canvas support) in the create.js docs. To reduce an image and keep small details your must ensure that the detail does not get smaller than a pixel. If you have a 200 pixel width image and scale it down to 100 any detail on the original smaller than 2 pixels will create noticeable artifacts. You best option is to rework the art nearer the scale it is rendered at.